# A Geordie connection with Hawaii?

Tags: etymology

I read somewhere the term "Wahini" is a Hawaiian expression for "A beautiful young girl" (confirmed in the Urban Dictionary).

Seeing as the islands were first visited by Captain Cook, and he actually perished there in the 1770's, and he was a "Geordie" - one raised in the North East of England around the city of Newcastle, he and his crew would have been familiar with the dialect expression "Wor Hinny" meaning "our girl", or "our lass".

I wonder if there is any definite proof out there that the words were adopted and corrupted to the current Hawaiian word...?

Comment: My understanding is that Cook wasn't a Geordie but from North Yorkshire (confirmed by a quick visit to Wikipedia). That's not a million miles away from Newcastle as the crow flies, admittedly, but light years away in terms of dialect. I've never heard anyone from North Yorks, or Teesside (another area of the north east that seems to claim him), use the word "hinny".

Comment: What if maybe Cook's crew brought it back from Polynesia and it showed up new in Newcastle?

Answer (score 11):

There's no connection.

The Geordie *[wor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wor#English)* is a variant of *our* and *[hinny](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hinny#Etymology_3)* is a term of endearment from the word *honey*.

The Hawaiian and Maori word *[wahine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wahine)* means *woman, female* or *wife*.

Comment: And the fact that it's in both Hawaiian and Maori shows that it goes **way** back in Austronesian history. The Maori went south to New Zealand and the Hawaiians east, both from somewhere around Tahiti.

Comment: Are you sure 'hinny' is from 'honey'? It's a female horse/donkey cross (I know this sounds weird as a term of endearment but no weirder than 'duck') and it's generally thought that this is the origin, not 'honey'. People don't really use 'honey' in that way in the northeast, for people you don't know. This is all personal experience though, not based on research.

Comment: @user26120: The (etymology) dictionaries I checked said it's from *honey*, and has been used in Scotland too. There was a Scottish example that clearly meant *honey* as it mentioned bees too.